# How to access object inside delegate

Tags: c#, delegates

I have a function delegate returning an object.
I am storing that object in a list.
I want to iterate through that list to get values in object, but in for loop I am not able to do so:

```
public static class Tracking
{
    public delegate TrackingObject GetTrackObject ();
    public static List<GetTrackObject> TrackedLists = new List<GetTrackObject>();

    public static void Register (GetTrackObject trackobject)
    {
        TrackedLists.Add(trackobject);
    }
}

public class TrackingObject
{
    object collection;
    Type T;
    Type K;
    Type V;

    public TrackingObject (object o, Type t, Type k, Type v)
    {
        collection = o;
        T = t;
        K = k;
        V = v;
    }
}

class TrackList<T> : List<T>
{
    public string Name = null;
    public int ItemCount;
    public int AvgSize;
    public int Size;

    public TrackList (string name, byte avgsize)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.AvgSize = avgsize;
        this.ItemCount = this.Count;
        this.Size = this.Count * this.AvgSize;

        Tracking.Register(this.GetTrackObject);
    }

    public TrackingObject GetTrackObject ()
    {
        TrackingObject TO = new TrackingObject(this, typeof(T), null, null);
        return TO;
    }
}

public static void Main ()
{
    foreach (Tracking.GetTrackObject method in Tracking.TrackedLists)
    { }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. What is your error? What is failing?

Comment: I must agree with @David Heffernan, this code looks awkward... the public fields to the reason behind the trackingobject delegate just puzzles me

Answer (score 1):

You are not storing the object in the list, you're storing the method to invoke (run) in the list.

One option is to invoke your method to get the result.

```
public static void Main ()
{
    foreach (Tracking.GetTrackObject method in Tracking.TrackedLists)
    {
        object trackedObject = method();
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively you could make your list a list of objects, and invoke the method in your Register method (and store the result in your list).